# How to get most repeated value from table in JPQL?

Tags: jpql

I'm developing a shopping web site application. I need to get the most popular item in the shop. I'm using `JPQL`. In other words I need to get the most repeated item code from table. I tried with this-

```
select o.item from OrderDetail o GROUP BY o.item.id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I got the following error.

```
unexpected token: LIMIT
```

How to fix this error?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setMaxResults()` on the query-Object created by the entity manager to limit the number of results

for example:

```
entityManager.createQuery(QUERY).setMaxResults(1);
```